# Change MongoDB from root to Sudo user

Tags: mongodb, centos, root, sudo

I currently have MongoDB installed on CentOS using root and need to change this to a Sudo user, while retaining all existing databases etc.

Is there a simple way to do this or do I need to uninstall MongoDB and then reinstall it.

I assume I will also need to change the owner of all db's from root to the Sudo user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@nevf, I would suggest a clean reinstall to avoid any permissions issues. What I would do:

- Stop MongoDB service
- Take a database dump
- Reinstall mongo using a sudo user

If you would like to go to the other way, AFAIK you would have to manually:

- Change owner of all data files /var/lib/mongo
- Change owner of all executable files ls /usr/bin/ | grep mongo
- Change owner of the config file /etc/mongod.conf

sudo chown -R user:user /directory/

- Modify the user who runs the service in the systemd file

Comment: thanks for the answer. In the end it turned out this wasn't the issue, but something else which I've now addressed.  I would agree though that a clean install is the best way to handle this.